# How do I connect two computers to one monitor with DisplayPort?

Tags: peripherals

I have two computers, they're not both on at the same time. I don't want to be switching the cable from one computer to the other all the time. Is there a way I can connect both computers to one DisplayPort input on the monitor?

Comment: This is not the forum for a question like this but the answer would be a KVM switch. You could also get a monitor with two DisplayPort inputs.

Comment: Thanks, where should I go if I didn't know the answer from you?